# Convert a CSV file to force encapsilation

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

My ideal fix would be a function that can take a CSV file that does not have forced encapsulation (no quotes around values if the value has no spaces or is just a number) and convert it into a CSV file that makes sure every field is encapsulated with double quotes.

```
<?php

$raw_file = BASE_DIR."pathto/csv.csv";
$fixed_file = BASE_DIR."pathto/fixed.csv";

convert_file($raw_file, $fixed_file);

//move on with life!!
?>
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to get the contents of your original csv file and [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) (using the fourth parameter) to build the encapsulated file.

For example, supposing your column separator is `;` :

```
<?php

$raw_file = BASE_DIR."pathto/csv.csv";
$fixed_file = BASE_DIR."pathto/fixed.csv";

// Getting contents
$raw_handle = fopen($raw_file, 'r');
$contents = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($raw_handle, 0, ';')) !== false) {
    $contents[] = $data;
}
fclose($raw_handle);

// Putting contents
$fixed_handle = fopen($fixed_file, 'w');
foreach ($contents as $line) {
    fputcsv($fixed_handle, $line, ';', '"');
}
fclose($fixed_handle);

//move on with life!!
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. With slight mods this method worked out great! thank you again for the response, you saved my night!

Comment: Glad to help ! Please mark the answer as accepted so it might help others in your situation.